# Isolate all words in a string and the number of (multibyte-safe) characters that preceeded each word

Tags: php, offset, preg-match-all, preg-split, multibyte-characters

I want to use `preg_split()` with its `PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option to capture both the word and the index where it begins in the original string.

However my string contains multibyte characters which is throwing off the counts. There doesn't seem to be a [`mb_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) equivalent to this. What are my options?

Example:

```php
$text = "Hello world — goodbye";

$words = preg_split("/(\w+)/x",
                    $text,
                    -1,
                    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach($words as $word) {
    print("$word[0]: $word[1]<br>");
}
```

This outputs:

> Hello: 0
>   : 5
>   world: 6
>   — : 11
>   goodbye: 16

Because the dash is is an em-dash, rather than a standard hyphen, it's a multibyte character - so "goodbye"s offset comes out as 16 instead of 14.

Comment: This thread seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605173/php-mb-split-capturing-delimiters

Comment: Thanks! However, if I try using the `mb_explode()` function from that question I get exactly the same result as `preg_split()`.

Comment: Do you think you might utilize [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php#117588) and loop the array looking for spaces?

Comment: A bit of a hack, but you could replace the mb character with a non multi-byte character, then run the preg_split() function on the string.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks but I’m not sure how looking for spaces would help - spaces aren’t a problem.

Comment: @dale landry I could but it’s a big text with a load of such characters, and I also the punctuation is important - I don’t want to change it.

Comment: I meant looping the array to find spaces in order to determine where the next word starts. If there's a space in the array and next index is not a space, that means a new word has started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over a year later I was revisiting this and came up with a function to do this better. The good thing is it handles multibyte strings without having to ditch the multibyte characters entirely. The bad thing is that it can't use a regular expression like `preg_split()` does.

```php
/**
 * Splits a piece of text into individual words and the words' position within
 * the text.
 *
 * @param string $text The text to split.
 * @return array Each element is an array, of the word and its 0-based position.
 */
function split_offset_capture($text) {
    $words = array();

    // We split into words based on these characters:
    $non_word_chars = array(
        " ", "-", "–", "—", ".", ",", ";" ,":", "(", ")", "/",
        "\\", "?", "!", "*", "'", "’", "\n", "\r", "\t",
    );

    // To keep track within the loop:
    $word_started = FALSE;
    $current_word = "";
    $current_word_position = 0;

    $characters = mb_str_split($text);

    foreach($characters as $i => $letter) {
        if ( ! in_array($letter, $non_word_chars)) {
            // A character in a word.
            if ( ! $word_started) {
                // We're starting a brand new word.
                if ($current_word != "") {
                    // Save the previous, now complete, word's info.
                    $words[] = array($current_word, $current_word_position);
                }
                $current_word_position = $i;
                $word_started = TRUE;
                $current_word = "";
            }
            $current_word .= $letter;
        } else {
            $word_started = FALSE;
        }
    };

    // Add on the final word.
    $words[] = array($current_word, $current_word_position);

    return $words;
}
```

Doing this:

```php
$text = "Héllo world — goodbye";

$words = split_offset_capture($text);
```

Ends up with `$words` containing this:

```php
array(
    array("Héllo", 0),
    array("world", 6),
    array("goodbye", 14),
);
```

You might need to add further characters to `$non_word_chars`.

For real-world texts one awkward thing is handling punctuation that immediately follows words (e.g. `Russ'` or `Russ’`), or within words (e.g. `Bob's`, `Bob’s` or `new-found`). To cope with this I came up with this altered function that has three arrays of characters to look for. So it perhaps does more than `preg_split()` but, again, doesn't use regular expressions:

```php
/**
 * Splits a piece of text into individual words and the words' position within
 * the text.
 *
 * @param string $text The text to split.
 * @return array Each element is an array, of the word and its 0-based position.
 */
function split_offset_capture_2($text) {
    $words = array();

    // We split into words based on these characters:
    $non_word_chars = array(
        " ", "-", "–", "—", ".", ",", ";" ,":", "(", ")", "/",
        "\\", "?", "!", "*", "'", "’", "\n", "\r", "\t"
    );

    // EXCEPT, these characters are allowed to be WITHIN a word:
    // e.g. "up-end", "Bob's", "O'Brien"
    $in_word_chars = array("-", "'", "’");

    // AND, these characters are allowed to END a word:
    // e.g. "Russ'"
    $end_word_chars = array("'", "’");

    // To keep track within the loop:
    $word_started = FALSE;
    $current_word = "";
    $current_word_position = 0;

    $characters = mb_str_split($text);

    foreach($characters as $i => $letter) {
        if ( ! in_array($letter, $non_word_chars)
            ||
            (
                // It's a non-word-char that's allowed within a word.
                in_array($letter, $in_word_chars)
                &&
                ! in_array($characters[$i-1], $non_word_chars)
                &&
                ! in_array($characters[$i+1], $non_word_chars)
            )
            ||
            (
                // It's a non-word-char that's allowed at the end of a word.
                in_array($letter, $end_word_chars)
                &&
                ! in_array($characters[$i-1], $non_word_chars)
            )
        ) {
            // A character in a word.
            if ( ! $word_started) {
                // We're starting a brand new word.
                if ($current_word != "") {
                    // Save the previous, now complete, word's info.
                    $words[] = array($current_word, $current_word_position);
                }
                $current_word_position = $i;
                $word_started = TRUE;
                $current_word = "";
            }
            $current_word .= $letter;
        } else {
            $word_started = FALSE;
        }
    };

    // Add on the final word.
    $words[] = array($current_word, $current_word_position);

    return $words;
}
```

So if we have:

```php
$text = "Héllo Bob's and Russ’ new-found folks — goodbye";
```

then the first function (`split_offset_capture()`) gives us:

```php
array(
    array("Héllo", 0),
    array("Bob", 6),
    array("s", 10),
    array("and", 12),
    array("Russ", 16),
    array("new", 22),
    array("found", 26),
    array("folks", 32),
    array("goodbye", 40),
);
```

While the second function (`split_offset_capture_2()`) gets us:

```php
array(
    array("Héllo", 0),
    array("Bob's", 6),
    array("and", 12),
    array("Russ’", 16),
    array("new-found", 22),
    array("folks", 32),
    array("goodbye", 40),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack, but seems to work. Use `str_replace()` to replace the multi-byte character with a non-multi-byte character and then run the `preg_split()` on the string.

```
$text = 'Hello world — goodbye';
$mb = '—';
$rplmnt = "X";

function chkPlc($text, $mb, $rplmnt){
    if(strpos($text, $mb) !== false){ 
        $rpl = str_replace($mb, $rplmnt, $text);
        $words = preg_split("/(\w+)/x",
                        $rpl,
                        -1,
                        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        foreach($words as $word) {    
            $stmt = print("$word[0]: $word[1]<br>");
        }
    }

    $stmt .= 'New String with replaced md char with non mb char: '.$rpl.'<br>';
    return $stmt;
}

chkPlc($text, $mb, $rplmnt);
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Hello: 0
: 5
world: 6
X : 11
goodbye: 14
```

A more in depth function could be written to check if a non-multi-byte character is not present within the string first, then used as a replacement for the multi-byte character defined. Again, kind of a hack but it works.

Comment: Thanks @dale landry. I found another solution, posted here, using mb_convert_encoding() that I guess has a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another not-ideal solution: convert the text to something like ISO-8859-1 using [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) that will get rid of the multibyte characters. They'll either be turned to a similar ASCII character or a question-mark.

So transforming `$text` before doing the `preg_split()` using this:

```php
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

Results in:

> Hello: 0
>   : 5
>   world: 6
>   ? : 11
>   goodbye: 14

Although it makes a mess of the text, you can still keep a copy of the original of course.

I found it via [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#90330) about the `iconv()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate all words in a string of text and keep track of the number of multibyte characters which came before it (not necessarily the "byte offset" of each word), you can use `preg_match_all()` and maintain a multibyte character count as you isolate subsequent words.

In my regex pattern, I am defining "words" as contiguous characters comprised of letters, backticks, single quotes, and hyphens.  All other characters will be deemed non-words in this context. You may adjust these definitions if/when required.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rHEpZ))

```
$text = "Héllo Bob's and Russ’ new-found folks — goodbye";

var_export(
    array_reduce(
        preg_match_all("~([^\p{L}`'-]*)([\p{L}`'-]+)~u", $text, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER) ? $m : [],
        function($result, $m) {
            static $last = 0;
            $last += mb_strlen($m[1]);
            $result[] = [$m[2] => $last];
            $last += mb_strlen($m[2]);
            return $result;
        },
        []
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Héllo' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Bob\'s' => 6,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'and' => 12,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Russ' => 16,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'new-found' => 22,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'folks' => 32,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'goodbye' => 40,
  ),
)
```